# How to Convert Bson Timestamp from Mongo changestream to UTC date format in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, timestamp, change-data-capture

eg: clusterTime = TimeStamp{value= 6948482818288648193, seconds = 16754329210, inc= 1}

When I read the value from document.getClusterTime().toString() the value returned is bson timestamp. And I want to convert this into UTC time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BSON timestamp value is a 64 bits number where the first 32 bits denote a count of seconds since the Unix epoch of 1970-01-01 at 00:00 UTC.

Given below is an excerpt from the mongoDB documentation:

> #### Timestamps
>
> BSON has a special timestamp type for *internal* MongoDB use
> and is not associated with the regular Date type. This internal
> timestamp type is a 64 bit value where:
>
> - the most significant 32 bits are a `time_t` value (seconds since the
>   Unix epoch)
> - the least significant 32 bits are an incrementing `ordinal`
>   for operations within a given second.

So for your example:

```
    long timestampValue = 6_948_482_818_288_648_193L;
    
    long unixTimestamp = timestampValue >> 32;
    Instant timestamp = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTimestamp);
    
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Output:

> 2021-04-07T18:22:07Z

The printed result is in UTC, denoted by the trailing `Z`.

**Link:** [BSON Types - MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: You are right, damned details... However BSON has a special timestamp type **for internal** MongoDB use, so `Timestamp` are rather uncommon.